# Remove html tags from cart item name in WooCommerce cart and checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[See the image for how it is getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/222LJ.png)
[My installed plugins in WP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbClG.png)

I wanted to remove the "span" element from the add to cart product title. I provided the both images one with problem and the other are my installed plugins.
I think its in the Boostify Header Footer Builder(The client says that).

Answer (score 1):

To remove HTML tags from product names in cart and in checkout, you can use the following:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'strip_html_tags_from_cart_item_name', 9000, 1 );
function strip_html_tags_from_cart_item_name( $product_name ) {
    $product_name = wp_strip_all_tags( $product_name, true );

    return $product_name;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Its working :)  ...
They are in table form like:
<dl class="variation">
   <dt class="variation-Size">Size:</dt>
  <dd class="variation-Size"><p>S</p>
</dd>
   <dt class="variation-Color">Color:</dt>
  <dd class="variation-Color"><p>Green</p>
</dd>
 </dl>

How do i edit this, they not in-lined